# Can not achieve sync between scrollview nav buttons and react native swiper tabs

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, swiper.js

Tried many ways, including using swiperRef, but I can not get sync between nav buttons and swiping content. Separately features work properly, but when I try to swipe after pressing tab button and in reverse, I got inadeqate results. I think the problem is that I can not handle swiper index properly, I'd be happy to get some good advice on this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, BackHandler, View } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
import InfoCard from './InfoCard';

const DetailsOverlay = ({ onClose }) => {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);

  const handleCloseBtnPress = () => {
    onClose();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      handleCloseBtnPress();
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      backAction
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);

  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('0');

  const handleTabPress = (tab) => {
    setActiveTab(tab);
    scrollToActiveTab(tab);
  };

  const scrollToActiveTab = (tab) => {
    const tabWidth = 100; 
    const offsetX = tabWidth * (parseInt(tab));
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ x: offsetX, animated: true });
  };

  const handleSwiperIndexChanged = (index) => {
    setActiveTab((index).toString());
    scrollToActiveTab((index).toString());
  };

  const tabContent = [
    {
      id: '0',
      title: 'Марии Ульяновой',
      cards: [
        { id: 'RV', row: '9' },
        { id: 'MG', row: '10' },
        { id: 'EF', row: '11' },
        { id: 'CT', row: '12' },
        { id: 'LS', row: '13' },
        { id: 'RT', row: '14' },
        { id: 'SR', row: '15' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'Троицк',
      cards: [
        { id: 'RV', row: '17' },
        { id: 'MG', row: '18' },
        { id: 'EF', row: '19' },
        { id: 'CT', row: '20' },
        { id: 'LS', row: '21' },
        { id: 'RT', row: '22' },
        { id: 'SR', row: '23' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'Академика Анохина',
      cards: [
        { id: 'RV', row: '25' },
        { id: 'MG', row: '26' },
        { id: 'EF', row: '27' },
        { id: 'CT', row: '28' },
        { id: 'LS', row: '29' },
        { id: 'RT', row: '30' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      title: 'Сумской проезд',
      cards: [
        { id: 'RV', row: '32' },
        { id: 'MG', row: '33' },
        { id: 'EF', row: '34' },
        { id: 'CT', row: '35' },
        { id: 'LS', row: '36' },
        { id: 'RT', row: '37' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      title: 'Обручева',
      cards: [
        { id: 'RV', row: '39' },
        { id: 'MG', row: '40' },
        { id: 'EF', row: '41' },
        { id: 'CT', row: '42' },
        { id: 'LS', row: '43' },
        { id: 'RT', row: '44' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      title: 'Ясная',
      cards: [
        { id: 'RV', row: '46' },
        { id: 'MG', row: '47' },
        { id: 'EF', row: '48' },
        { id: 'CT', row: '49' },
        { id: 'LS', row: '50' },
        { id: 'RT', row: '51' },
        { id: 'SR', row: '52' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: '6',
      title: 'Офис',
      cards: [
        { id: 'CT', row: '54' },
        { id: 'SR', row: '55' },
      ],
    }

  return (
    <View style={styles.overlayScreen}>
      <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.tabContentContainer}
          horizontal
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          ref={scrollViewRef}
        >
          {tabContent.map((tab) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={tab.id}
              style={[styles.tab, activeTab === tab.id && styles.activeTab]}
              onPress={() => handleTabPress(tab.id)}
            >
              <Text style={[styles.tabText, activeTab === tab.id && styles.tabTextActive]}>
                {tab.title}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>

      <Swiper
        loop={false}
        showsPagination={false}
        index={parseInt(activeTab)}
        onIndexChanged={handleSwiperIndexChanged}
      >
        {tabContent.map((tab) => (
          <ScrollView
            key={tab.id}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.overlayContent}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          >
            <Text key="header" style={styles.header}>
              {tab.title}
            </Text>
            {tab.cards.map((card) => (
              <InfoCard key={card.id} row={card.row} />
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Method that I tried, it was close, but ScrollView starts to set random active tabs

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, BackHandler, View } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
import InfoCard from './InfoCard';

const DetailsOverlay = ({ onClose }) => {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);
  const swiperRef = useRef(null);

  const handleCloseBtnPress = () => {
    onClose();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      handleCloseBtnPress();
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      backAction
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);

  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState('0');
  const [swipeIndex, setSwipeIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleTabPress = (tab) => {
    setActiveTab(tab);
    const index = parseInt(tab);
    setSwipeIndex(index);
    swiperRef.current.scrollTo(index, true);
  };

.......

 return (
    <View style={styles.overlayScreen}>
      <View style={styles.tabContainer}>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.tabContentContainer}
          horizontal
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          ref={scrollViewRef}
        >
          {tabContent.map((tab) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={tab.id}
              style={[styles.tab, activeTab === tab.id && styles.activeTab]}
              onPress={() => handleTabPress(tab.id)}
            >
              <Text style={[styles.tabText, activeTab === tab.id && styles.tabTextActive]}>
                {tab.title}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ))}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>

      <Swiper
        loop={false}
        showsPagination={false}
        index={swipeIndex}
        onIndexChanged={setSwipeIndex}
        ref={swiperRef}
      >
        {tabContent.map((tab) => (
          <ScrollView
            key={tab.id}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.overlayContent}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          >
            <Text key="header" style={styles.header}>
              {tab.title}
            </Text>
            {tab.cards.map((card) => (
              <InfoCard key={card.id} row={card.row} />
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you try this or get inspired on how they implemented it - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-view/